# c# implicit cast from dependent assembly throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, casting

Suppose I have two projects:

### Project1

A class library

```
using System;

namespace Project1
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo(object bar){
            Bar = (Bar)bar;
        }

        public Bar Bar { get;}
    }

    public class Bar{
        public string MyBar {get; set;}
    }
}
```

#### Project2

An exe

```
using System;
using Project1;

namespace Project2
{
    public class BarTrip
    {
        public string MyFoo {get;set;}

        public static implicit operator Bar(BarTrip trip){
            return new Bar{ MyBar = trip.MyFoo };
        }
    }

    public static class Program{
        public static void Main(params string[] args){
            var trip = new BarTrip(){ MyFoo = "Aaron" };
            var foo = new Foo(trip);

            Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar.MyBar);
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that when I run my exe that the implicit cast operator I defined inside `BarTrip` would be invoked once the casting operation inside `Foo`'s constructor is invoked.

Instead I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Project2.BarTrip' to type 'Project1.Bar'.
   at Project1.Foo..ctor(Object bar)
   at Project2.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\TestProjects\Project2\src\Project2\Program.cs:line 18
```

What's the reason for this error and what could I do to make this scenario workable if Project1 is a blackbox DLL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When this is compiled, there's no type information passed to the context of `Foo`'s constructor, it's just `object`. So then the implicit cast isn't resolved. The explicit cast fails because there isn't a well defined path.

This seems like the perfect case for an interface defined in your class library.

Comment: Thanks, that is sure what it looks like. Extracting an interface from `Bar` is probably the right way to go.